# Table data not showing using Nodejs console application

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I want to display the customer table data.I am using SQL Server 2014. But it is only displaying "Server is running instead. I have installed all the npm packages and I am running from console.

Node hello.js
The result is "Server is running"

The code is shown below.

```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Password13',
        server: 'localhost/SQLEXPRESS',
        database: 'hellodb',

        option: {
            instanceName: "MSSQLSERVER", // update me
            database: 'hellodb' // update me
        }
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from customertbl', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

          });
       });
     });

    var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
     console.log('Server is running..');
   });
```

Comment: How are you hitting get request? 
localhost:5000/

Comment: Yes its hiiting but displaying a blank page.

Comment: Just check what result you are getting
console.log(recordset) before sending the response.

Comment: I think `server: 'localhost/SQLEXPRESS'` should just be `server: 'localhost'` - you're specifying the instance name in options - which also means `option` should be `options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your SQL configuration object When specifying instance name along with host, config should be something as below:

```
var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Password13',
        server: 'localhost\\instancename',
        database: 'hellodb'  
    };
```

Alternatively you can pass instance details as options parameter:

```
var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Password13',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'hellodb',
        options: {
            instanceName: "instance name"   
        }
    };
```

You made 2 mistakes in config obj:

1. The server parameter should be as `localhost\\instance` not `localhost/instance` when the instance details passed along with the server.
2. it's `options` not `option` in config obj.

   Further reading: https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#connect-callback

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It might help.

```
var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Password13',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'hellodb',

        options: {
            instanceName: "MSSQLSERVER", // update me
        }
    };
```